# Asp.net ScriptManager history management not working: state is always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, updatepanel, scriptmanager

I'm experimenting with asp.net's `UpdatePanel` and `ScriptManager` controls to ajax-enable a page, and I wanted to implement "history" using `ScriptManager`'s `AddHistoryPoint()` facility.

Here's a fragment of my page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="searchScriptManager" AsyncPostBackTimeout="6000" EnableHistory="true" OnNavigate="searchScriptManager_Navigate"/>

<div class="container">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updPanelSearch">
       ...stuff....
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

So, when some button or other control triggers an event in code behind, I add a HistoryPoint as follows:

```
protected void btnPerformSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do stuff...

        searchScriptManager.AddHistoryPoint("actionDone", "search");
    }
```

This seems to work properly:the URL of my page changes and when I press back the `Navigate` event of the ScriptManager fires correctly. Here's the problem tho. In my handler for the Navigate event the State dictionary is always empty, making it impossible to handle things properly:

```
 protected void searchScriptManager_Navigate(object sender, HistoryEventArgs e)
    {
        string d = e.State["actionDone"]; //PROBLEM: e.State is always an empty dictionary, d will always be null!!!
        if (d == "search")
        {
            //hide search results...
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?